# Removing a vintage breeze block (decorative concrete block) wall

Tags: concrete, walls

Can anyone offer any input on how i can remove some vintage breeze blocks (decorative concrete block) from between 2 concrete walls? The block wall is 3 blocks high and 7 blocks wide set between solid concrete.. I'm Trying to take it down without destroying the blocks.
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: A picture would help, but probably will come down to a heavy hammer and a chisel for cement/mortar to loosen the mortar between the blocks.  Work from top to bottom.  The mortar is usually softer than the blocks.

Comment: Yup. 4 pound hand sledge and a 3-4" wide masonry chisel.

Comment: The without destroying condition takes all the fun out of it.